# How to configure oh-my-zsh to remember directory specific unique commands

Tags: ubuntu, plugins, configuration, oh-my-zsh

I want to configure my oh-my-zsh to have remember "unique" commands which are used in a given directory.

My current plugins are

```
plugins=(git fzf zsh-autosuggestions)
```

the `fzf` let me search through my commands and shows me a nice history but a lot of them are duplicated and sometimes i want to see commands which i ran in my `db` directory.

I tried using `per-directory-history` but it messed up with fzf i.e., it didn't show me list of commands which meets given string.

Whats the best way to configure oh-my-zsh for this use-case